# $x+y=xy=w \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Is $x^w+y^w$ real?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

**Question:** For $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$, suppose $x+y=xy=w \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Is $x^w+y^w$ necessarily real?

For instance, if $x+y=xy=3$, then one solution is $x = \frac{3 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, $y = \frac{3 \mp i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, but $x^3 + y^3 = 0$, which is real.

I've checked this numerically for many values of $w$ that give complex $x$ and $y$ (namely, $w \in (0,4)$.)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Then $x+y$ isn't real.

Comment: @PatrickStevens But he required that $x+y=xy\in\Bbb R$..

Comment: Sorry all. I wasn't paying attention, clearly.

Comment: The answer is yes; the essential idea is that $xy = x+y \in \mathbb{R}$ forces either that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, or that $x$ and $y$ are complex conjugates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**
Since $x + y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$y = \overline{x} + r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then $xy = |x|^2 + xr \in \mathbb{R}$, implying that either $r = 0$ or $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we do casework:

- If $r = 0$, then $y = \overline{x}$; this leads to

  $$x^w + y^w = x^w + \overline{x^w} \in \mathbb{R}.$$

  **Warning:** for this to work, we had to pick the standard branch of the complex logarithm, specifically, the one undefined on the nonpositive real line, whose imaginary part is between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Once we define $z^w := e^{w \ln z}$, ${(\overline{x})}^w = \overline{x^w}$ is true for this branch of $\ln$ (as $x$ is not nonpositive real), but might not be true for another branch.

  This warning does not come into play when $w$ is an integer. But take, for example, $x = 1 + \frac{1 + i}{\sqrt{2}}$, $y = 1 + \frac{1 - i}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $x + y = xy = 2 + \sqrt{2}$. If we picked a different branch of the complex logarithm, then we could have $x^w + y^w$ not real.
- On the other hand, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $x^w + y^w \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $x + y = xy > 0$, $x,y$ must both be positive, so we have no trouble with a negative base of the exponent.

---

Note there was nothing special about $w$: we could have reached the stronger conclusion that $x^a + y^a \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You do need $x,y\geq0$, for your last statement.

Comment: @6005: Even with $a>0$, you *still* need $x,y\not\le 0$. Consider $x=y=-1\in\mathbb R$ and $a=1/2>0$. Then no matter where you do the branch cut,  either $x^a=y^a=i$ or $x^a=y^a=-i$. Basically, the equation $\overline x^a = \overline{x^a}$ is nor true for all $x$ if $a$ is not integer.

Comment: As a second conjecture, I believe the casework depends on the value of $w$. That is, in fact $r = 0$ if and only if $0< w < 4$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $w \geq 4$ ($w = 0$ is excluded by assumption).

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for your valuable feedback. I believe I fixed all the problems and provided all the necessary caveats.

Comment: @DrewN your second conjecture is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Write $x=a+bi$, $y=c-di$, then clearly $b=d$ because $x+y$ is real.

So   $x=a+bi$, $y=c-bi$. Then $xy=ac-abi+cbi+b^2$, so $a=c$ or $b=0$.

- If $a=c$, then $y = \overline{x}$, i.e. the complex conjugate of $x$.
  So $x^w+y^w = x^w+(\overline{x})^w = x^w+\overline{x^w}$, which is
  real.
- If $b=0$, $x$ and $y$ are real so $x^w+y^w$ is real as $w>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on my answer earlier. In your answer, note that $(\overline{x})^w = \overline{x^w}$ is only true for a particular branch of complex log, and will never be true for negative real $x$. However, you can guarantee it for all $x$ which aren't negative real by picking the relevant branch of complex log to define your exponential.

Answer (score 4):

$x+y$ real implies that $\Im(x)=-\Im(y)$. Thus if $x=a+bi$ then $y=c-bi$.

$xy$ real implies that, because $xy=ac+b^2+ib(c-a)$, $b=0\lor c=a$.

If $b=0$ the result is trivial as $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $c=a$ then $x=\overline{y}$. But then clearly 
$$x^w+y^w=x^w+\overline{x}^w=\overline{x^w+\overline{x}^w}=\overline{x^w+y^w},$$
where the middle equality holds by symmetry.

But then it must be real, as the only complex numbers satisfying $z=\bar{z}$ are real.

Note: for why/when we are allowed to write $x^w=\overline{\bar{x}^w}$ refer to  @6005's answer

Comment: Actually, $x = \overline{(\overline{x})^w}$ is a bit more complicated; it's not sufficient that $w$ is real. We have to pick a definition of complex exponential that allows for the *symmetry* that you appeal to. But regardless of which definition we take (branch of complex log), $x^w = \overline{(\overline{x})^w}$ will be false for $x$ negative real. Consider $w = \tfrac12$.

Comment: Yeah. That is indeed true. I'll add in my answer to look at yours for a more detailed explanation on when/why this works.